# clang-8: getting typedef information from DeclRefExpr node in AST

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-static-analyzer

I have below test code:

```
typedef void (*funcPtrType)()
funcPtrType FPT;

void myFunc(){
    
}

int main(){
    FPT = myFunc;
    FPT();
    return 0;
}
```

And following is the part of AST dump of this code:

[image: ASTDump]

My question is, from which API can I get the 'void (*)()' information from DeclRefExpr node?

[image: dclrfxpr]

Already tried dynamic casting this node to VarDecl but from it I could not reach the information I mentioned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a [`DeclRefExpr`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1DeclRefExpr.html), that is an expression that refers to a declared entity.  Call the `getDecl` method to get the associated [`ValueDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ValueDecl.html), which is the declaration itself.  On that object, call `getType` to get the [`QualType`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1QualType.html), which is the type, possibly including cv-qualifiers.

For example:

```
DeclRefExpr const *dre = ...;      // wherever you got it
ValueDecl const *decl = dre->getDecl();
QualType type = decl->getType();
```

In this case, the type is a `typedef`.  To inspect the underlying type, call `getTypePtr` to get the unqualified type, then `getUnqualifiedDesugaredType` to skip typedefs:

```
clang::Type const *underType = type.getTypePtr()->getUnqualifiedDesugaredType();
```

You can then call, for example, `underType->isPointerType()` to find out if it is a pointer type, etc.  See the documentation for [`clang::Type`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Type.html) for other ways to query it.

If you want to get a string representation of `underType`, use the static `QualType::print` method, something like this:

```
LangOptions lo;
PrintingPolicy pp(lo);
std::string s;
llvm::raw_string_ostream rso(s);
QualType::print(underType, Qualifiers(), rso, lo, llvm::Twine());
errs() << "type as string: \"" << rso.str() << "\"\n";
```

For your example, this will print:

```
type as string: "void (*)()"
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but my actual question is how to find the pointer declaration after I find out underType->isPointerType() is true? As in the question I need the "void(*)()" information as string.

Comment: Ok, I added information on how to get a string representation of the type.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the information I was looking for.